# Univers font doesn't work with IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I have a question, the font Univers Utra condensed doesn't work with IE, while it works with all other browser. Anyone have an idea ?

My code below :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_fontscore.com_u-univers-lt-std-59-ultra-condensed';
    src: url('http://fontsforweb.com/public/fonts/8898/univers.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/fontscore.com_u-univers-lt-std-59-ultra-condensed.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Univers 59 Ultra Condensed.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/fontscore.com_u-univers-lt-std-59-ultra-condensed.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: try adding other fonts... if they work then it is problem of "univers" fonts. else it is problem of the code you are implementing.

Comment: Does it work in IE10 if you get rid of the EOT line?

Comment: Thanks for answers, i will try this and come back to you